# Visual Studio - Wanting to rename friendly names such as user story / epic / backlog lables to something else

Tags: azure-devops, rename, tfs-workitem, user-stories, backlog

We are wanting to rename the labels in Visual Studio rather than using the default names.  For example: Renaming "User Story" to say "Cards"

I've tried a few things but to no avail to amend the User Story & Epic labeles.
- Inheirted default AGILE 
- Tried to amend the current work item (User Story).
- I could amend the fields but not the text "User story" as it was greyed out.

[Greyed_Out_User_Story_Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btaYD.png)

I could create a new work item but then it looks like I need to recreate all the fields - unless there is a option to clone from another work item?
[New_Work_Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L099d.png)

I couldn't find an area to change the "Backlog" wording.  After changing this, would I still receive updates from Micosoft or would the butchering have caused major problems?

Any help would be great as i've searched and unable to find anything like this.

Comment: Why stray from convention? It increases the barrier to entry for new team members when they arrive. They have to learn a whole new set of terminology when they're already used to the conventional terminology for basically the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It’s impossible to change the name of the inherited WITs** (such as user story, epic etc).

For the inherited WITs, as you found, it can only change the Description, Icon and Icon color (not the name).

For inherited WITs, you can:

> - Add/remove custom fields
> - Add/remove custom groups
> - Add/delete custom pages
> - Add/remove a custom control
> - Enable/disable

And both for inherited WITs and custom WITs, you can not change the names.

More detail about what you can (not) change for inherited WITs, you can refer [What you can customize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/process/customize-process-wit#what-you-can-customize).